# parsing sdf file, performance issue

Tags: python, performance, sdf

I've wrtien a script which read different files and search molecular ID in big sdf databases (about 4.0 GB each).

the idea of this script is to copy every molecules from a list of id (about 287212 molecules) from my original databases to a new one in a way to have only one single copy of each molecule (in this case, the first copy encountered)

I've writen this script:

```
import re
import sys
import os

def sdf_grep (molname,files):
    filin = open(files, 'r')
    filine= filin.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(filine)):
        if filine[i][0:-1] == molname and filine[i][0:-1] not in past_mol:
            past_mol.append(filine[i][0:-1])
            iterate = 1
            while iterate == 1:
                if filine[i] == "$$$$\n":
                    filout.write(filine[i])
                    iterate = 0
                    break
                else:
                    filout.write(filine[i])
                i = i+1
        else:
            continue
    filin.close()

mol_dock = os.listdir("test")
listmol = []
past_mol = []
imp_listmol = open("consensus_sorted_surflex.txt", 'r')
filout = open('test_ini.sdf','wa')

for line in imp_listmol:
    listmol.append(line.split('\t')[0])
print 'list ready... reading files'
imp_listmol.close()

for f in mol_dock:
    print 'reading '+f
    for molecule in listmol:
        if molecule not in past_mol:
            sdf_grep(molecule , 'test/'+f) 

print len(past_mol)
filout.close()
```

it works perfectely, but it is very slow... too slow for what I need. Is there a way to rewrite this script in a way that can reduce the computation time?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you have three nested loops: molecular documents, molecules and file parsing *in the inner loop*. That smells like trouble - I mean, [quadratic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). You should move huge files parsing outside of inner loop and use set or dictionary for molecules.
Something like this:

1. For each sdf file
2. For each line, if it is molecule definition
3. Check in dictionary of unfound molecules
4. If present, process it and remove from dictionary of unfound molecules

This way, you will parse each sdf file exactly once, and with each found molecule, speed will further increase.

Comment: yeah, this is a solution I'm testing right now, it seems to be way more faster...

Answer (score 2):

Let `past_mol` be a set, rather than a list. That will speed up

```
filine[i][0:-1] not in past_mol
```

since checking membership in a set is O(1), while checking membership in a list is O(n).

---

Try not to write to a file one line at a time. Instead, save up lines in a list, join them into a single string, and then write it out with **one call** to `filout.write`.

---

It is generally better not to allow functions to modify global variables. `sdf_grep` modifies the global variable `past_mol`.

By adding `past_mol` to the arguments of `sdf_grep` you make it explicit that `sdf_grep` depends on the existence of `past_mol` (otherwise, `sdf_grep` is not really a standalone function).

If you pass `past_mol` in as a third argument to `sdf_grep`, then Python will make a new local variable named `past_mol` which will point to the same object as the global variable `past_mol`. Since that object is a set and a set is a mutable object, `past_mol.add(sline)` will affect the global variable `past_mol` as well.

As an added bonus, Python looks up local variables faster than global variables:

```
def using_local():
    x = set()
    for i in range(10**6):
        x

y = set
def using_global():
    for i in range(10**6):
        y

In [5]: %timeit using_local()
10 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit using_global()
10 loops, best of 3: 41 ms per loop
```

---

`sdf_grep` can be simplified greatly if you use a variable (let's call it `found`) which keeps track of whether or not we are inside one of the chunks of lines we want to keep. (By "chunk of lines" I mean one that begins with `molname` and ends with `"$$$$"`):

```
import re
import sys
import os

def sdf_grep(molname, files, past_mol):
    chunk = []
    found = False
    with open(files, 'r') as filin:
        for line in filin:
            sline = line.rstrip()
            if sline == molname and sline not in past_mol:
                found = True
                past_mol.add(sline)
            elif sline == '$$$$':
                chunk.append(line)                
                found = False
            if found:
                chunk.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(chunk)


def main():
    past_mol = set()
    with open("consensus_sorted_surflex.txt", 'r') as imp_listmol:
        listmol = [line.split('\t')[0] for line in imp_listmol]
        print 'list ready... reading files'

    with open('test_ini.sdf', 'wa') as filout:
        for f in os.listdir("test"):
            print 'reading ' + f
            for molecule in listmol:
                if molecule not in past_mol:
                    filout.write(sdf_grep(molecule, os.path.join('test/', f), past_mol))

        print len(past_mol)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you for your advices, it permit me to improve my script velocity in a significant way.